# Show/hide navigationBar when view is pushed/popped in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios8

Hi fellow developers,

I'm suprised that I didn't find any information on that particular use case for iOS 8. Let me explain, I have a navigation controller stack, the first view has it's navigationBar hidden, when the user clicks on a cell a new view is pushed and I need the navigation bar shown on this view to go back (obviously). On iOS 7 it was just a matter of adding this line in viewWillAppear  :

```
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

And it works like a charm. But as of iOS 8 I'm struggling to have the same behavior. For now I managed to do the same by using :

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
         self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
         self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
         self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, 0, 0, 0);
}    }
```

And changing the contentInset of my collectionsView / tableviews whatever I need to display. It'll work, but it's a real pain in the *** (sometimes the content inset isn't necessary if the user comes from a new viewcontroller).

For context the project was first developed to handle iOS 6 and 7, so no storyboard, all is done programmatically. I ported the app to a more modern codebase and made it universal.

Am I missing something ? Is there a better way to handle that in iOS 7/8 ?

Comment: We had the same issue. It seems this has been resolved with iOS 8.1 though.

Comment: I have similar issue with UIPageViewController in iOS 8. Kindly let me know any suggestions regarding issue if you have. You can get to my question thread below. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420396/adding-viewcontrollers-view-as-subview-to-uipageviewcontroller-in-ios-8-gives-w

Answer (score 14):

You want to hide it in `viewWillAppear` and show it again in `viewWillDisappear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Do this animated to get a smooth transition:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: out of all the answers i looked at here, and although many were like this above, this was the first one i read so i will up vote you :3 

Oddly enough i expected the animation to be different... how weird

Answer (score 9):

I thought line is :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

I check for it and it's work fine for me . . .
Try it . . .

Answer (score 7):

On `iOS 8`, it seems `navigationBarHidden` is not the same as `navigationBar.hidden`.
(I am building with deployment target `iOS 6` -- not sure if this makes a difference).

In my code, looking at the debugger with following *consecutive* lines:

```
bool b1 = self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden; // FALSE

bool b2 = self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden; // TRUE
```

`b1` shows as false and `b2` as true.

Setting `self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = false` solves the problem

Comment: I'm nodding. [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; by itself in my viewWillAppear method is working on iOS8.4 to hide the nav bar. This bug just appeared in my code. Previously (e.g., prior to iOS8.4) I was using navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES; prior to viewWillAppear, and it worked. But not now.

Comment: This did the for me using iOS 8.0 and above

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I really tried everything, but the navigation bar did not show up. Finally I realized I had this code in my first view controller :-)

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

I thought, somebody else that checks this question, did my mistake, so I thought it may worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple techniques. The less friction one would be:

```
open class ViewController: UIViewController {
  open var hidesNavigationBarWhenPushed = false

  override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(hidesNavigationBarWhenPushed, animated: animated)
  }
}
```

But that would give you this [result](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*xQqdDVwfl7y6KhUHVWTCzg.gif).

Alternatively, I would suggest using my newly built [HidesNavigationBarWhenPushed library](https://github.com/gontovnik/HidesNavigationBarWhenPushed/). [Here is the explanation](https://medium.com/@gontovnik/implementing-hidesnavigationbarwhenpushed-on-uiviewcontroller-10d8a68bca86) of how it works and why I built it.