# Adding ViewController's View as subview to UIPageViewController in iOS 8 gives weird UINavigationBar while show/hide

Tags: iphone, ios8, xcode6, uipageviewcontroller

I have been working on a project where I needed to show list of images with zoom / swipe feature as presented view modal. I created custom `ImageViewer` using `ContainerView` in which I have added `UIPageViewController`. And on demand, I added ImageViews over the `UIPageViewcontroller's` view. When user taps to `imageView`, the top `UINavigation` gets shown and hidden on toggle basis.

Everything worked as expected in iOS 7.1 and less.  However when I tested the functionality in iOS 8 devices and simulator, the `ImageViews` were not added to UIPageViewController in TopLeft ( beneath `UINavigationBar` ). It is added below the `NavigationBar` as shown in bug_iOS_8.png below.

[image]

Once I touch the buggy view, it repositions itself to correct position as in image expected.png below.

[image]

I have created and tested the issue in sample project and it seems it is bug in iOS 8 itself with `UIPageViewController`. I went through couple of questions regarding weird behavior of `UIPageViewController` too. Please check the sample app [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0a3uirpz56c3gtx/Transluscency.zip?dl=0) and kindly let me know if anyone has any hints on what is going on.

Thank you for your time and help.

PS: BTW I am using following version of Xcode. [image: Xcode Version]

Update 1:

I have tried as per the pin suggestions. However, the problem aligning is with the main view of UIViewController rather than its subview. In below image, Yellow is main View of UIViewController and red one is added subview, I added pin to "red" on in reference to superview "yellow" one. Please check following screen shots.

On startup.

[image]

After touch on screen.

[image]

Kind Regards,

Comment: hey nice screenshot..

Comment: Sort of uncomfortable to view the screenshots in Germany ;)

Answer (score 0):

check in storyboard for particular viewController and make sure Extended Edges >> Under top bars is not selected.

Comment: I want the Under Top Bars selected as my view will go behind the top bar. And when user taps on photo or view, the Top Bar Hides and shows. In iOS 7 it works fine but in iOS 8 it is buggy :( Thank you for pointing to above direction however it didn't seems to work out for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and the way i fixed it was select the view being added to the UIPageViewController in the storyboard and selected the pin options. Below in the image you can see the Constrain to margins options, make sure you unselect that. Also when choosing what view to pin it to make sure you select the superview and not the Top Layout Guide. [image]

Comment: Thanks for providing some hints. However, the problem aligning is with the main view of UIViewController rather than its subview. Please check "Update 1" on main question which i updated based on your answer, but problem continues to persists :(

Comment: is the yellow view pinned correctly to the uipageviewcontroller?

Comment: Yes it is pinned Correctly, However I found the answer for the issue.  I will post it in answer section. Thanks for you effort and suggestions. It really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Curious are you hiding your nav controller like this?

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

also if you have multiple Nav controllers, you might need to check you are referencing the correct one.

If you want it to be hidden when you present the ViewController you should move it to

```
    -(void) ViewWillAppear{
}
```

Comment: Yes I am hidding and showing nav controller using         [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]; on a selector. The selector is called when imageView is clicked. When ImageView is clicked new ViewController with NavigationController is presented from parent view using [self presentViewController:...].